# Transit time in Ataturk Instanbul airport rescheduled by Turkish airlines

Tags: transit, layovers, turkish-airlines, isl

I have a similar question to [1hr 30min layover in Ataturk Airport (Istanbul)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44816/1hr-30min-layover-in-ataturk-airport-istanbul) , but somewhat different.

My family is flying Lisbon->Istambul->Manila with a transit stop in Ataturk Airport at the end of the month of October. A single ticket covers both legs of the flight.

Turkish airlines just sent a message today, an email in Turkish (God knows why - they speak English), and two SMSes in English telling them their last leg departure was brought forward by 30 minutes.

The point is that they bought that flight because they had 2h20m to do transit, and now they only have 1h50m or less (minus the standard 15 minutes delay for Economy class?), so they should have now 1h35m to change connecting flights.

It is the first time they will be navigating that particular airport.

While the  last question states it is possible to do it; my question is a bit different; what steps do they have to take to minimize the problems, and not for instance going by a route different from the transit one? Is Ataturk easy to navigate, and has it plenty of English signs? Any advice on the route to take inside the airport?

In the meanwhile I also found this related question, [Need guidance on how to navigate Istanbul Atatürk Airport (IST)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/76153/need-guidance-on-how-to-navigate-istanbul-atat%C3%BCrk-airport-ist?rq=1) , which gives invaluable tips and states it can be a close call *if going through security control*.

Comment: 1h35 is enough layover time given the fact that the Airline reduced it by 30 minutes itself and will be aware that any unreasonable time will cause a number of issues for passengers and for the airline itself

Comment: Ataturk is large and parts of it can be crowded, but it's well-signed.

Comment: I am confused by "both legs are a single ticket": do you mean that you have a single ticket that includes both legs (i.e., one ticket per person) or that each leg has its own ticket (i.e., two tickets per person)?

Comment: A single ticket that includes both legs.

Comment: @HankyPanky I wouldn't assume that — I've had some airlines reschedule me into impossible connections (i.e., the second leg departing before the first arrives!).

Comment: All went well in the end. In the way to Manila, they did not make us go through customs as the connection time was very short, we were actually running to make it in 35-40 minutes, and then....delayed flight. Bummer. In the way back, where we had a 2h30m layover, we cleared immigration in around 20-30 minutes, and used the remaining time for shopping. Hint: do not buy perfumes in the way to holidays, if the bottles have more than 100ml