# Transit at Atatürk airport

Tags: transit, isl

I am traveling from Dusseldorf to Istanbul and then from Istanbul to Beirut on December 22nd. I have 2 hours between my 2 flights. Both flights are with Turkish Airlines.

Do you think this is enough time? Do I have to go through security check again?

Comment: Whether the time is enough is subjective but yes you do have to go through security again

Comment: I used the Atatürk Airport already 4 times as transit for flights from germany to international destinations. From my personal experience I would say "yes, 2h is fine"

Comment: Believe me that 2 hours is fine, and you can do it in 35-40m if they want to https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/96079/transit-time-in-ataturk-instanbul-airport-rescheduled-by-turkish-airlines

Comment: Related: [Need guidance on how to navigate Istanbul Atatürk Airport (IST)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/76153/3221)

Answer (score 4):

I've transited through this airport a handful of times in the last 6 months. About half the time after disembarking there is someone on the airbridge who will let you go directly to departures if you already have an onward boarding pass to show them. The other half of the time, there's been nobody there and I've had to go to transit security. Typically that has been quite quick and I've been through in 10 minutes or less.

Two hours is more than enough in my experience.